# How to set image path to lookup column?

Tags: 2013, custom-list, lookup-column, picture-library

I have a custom list having `lookup` with a picture library. But when I am creating `lookup` it just gives some of the columns like `Title`, `Created`, `Modified`, etc. it do not gives any value like `FileRef` or image URL or something like this.

Actually on creating new item when I add lookup value on saving that item in lookup field I want to show looked up image.

Is that any possible way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of SharePoint. This is how it works. You will not get the Image URL or FileRef as a lookup column from picture library.

Here is an [ARTICLE](http://blogs.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=53) that explains about Using the Lookup column to display an Image.

Another [ARTICLE](http://aaclage.blogspot.com/2013/10/create-simple-custom-lookup-picker-in.html) that might help you but it would create a custom lookup through JavaScript.